# Help in understanding proof of Möbius Inversion Formula

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Help in understanding proof of Möbius Inversion Formula

Could someone clarify why the equality $$\sum_{d^{'} | (n/d)} \mu(d) f(d^{'}) \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) F(n/d) =  \sum_{d | n} \sum_{d^{'} | (n/d)} \mu(d) f(d^{'})$$, in the below proof, is true ?

Also is there some rigorous way of proving that "As $d$ runs over the positive divisors of $n$ so does $d^{'}$ ?

[image]

Comment: Can you explain where you are stumped in this nice explaination? The pairs $(d,d')$ with $dd'|n$ can be equally characterized by $d|n$ and $d'|(n/d)$ and symmetrically by $d'|n$ and $d|(n/d')$.

Comment: @LutzL: What I understand from the OP's question is that he understand what's going intuitively, but he's asking for a formal way of demonstrating that fact rigorously.

Comment: It is mostly the equality I dont understand.

Comment: @user111854: Your question asked for a rigorous way to prove why $d'$ runs over positive divisors of $n$ as $d$ does. Which equality you don't understand? Would you single it out please?

Comment: The second line of my question.

Comment: I'd say the stated formula makes no sense. The order of summation has to be first $d:d|n$, and only after $d$ was defined can you sum over $d':d'|(n/d)$.

Comment: The proof is from Koshy book of elementary number theory.

Comment: Yes, in the image all the formulas are correctly stated. It is your formula above it that is not correctly parseable.

Comment: Do you mean this one? $\sum_{d^{'} | (n/d)} \mu(d) f(d^{'}) \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) F(n/d) =  \sum_{d | n} \sum_{d^{'} | (n/d)} \mu(d) f(d^{'})$? I'm afraid that this equality makes no sense as LutzL said. How did you come to this one? It's not written in the proof of your book.

Comment: Ohh I see it now. The sums are not products but it is a new line.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D_n$ be the set of positive divisors of $n$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then you have to show that the function$f: D_n \to D_n$ given by $\displaystyle f(d) = \frac{n}{d}$ is well-defined and bijective.

1. It's well defined because if $d \mid n$ then $\exists q \in \mathbb{N}: dq=n$, thus $\displaystyle q=\frac{n}{d}$, but $q.d = n$, therefore $q \mid n$, in other words, $\displaystyle \frac{n}{d} \mid n$, hence, $f(n) \in D_n$ and since division is a well-defined arithmetic operation, we see that $f$ is well-defined.
2. $f$ is injective because if $f(d_1)=f(d_1)$ then $\displaystyle \frac{n}{d_1}=\frac{n}{d_2}$ which gives $d_1 = d_2$.
3. $f$ is surjective because for any $d \in D_n$, there exists $\displaystyle \frac{n}{d} \in D_n$ such that $\displaystyle f(\frac{n}{d})=d$.

What I just proved is that $f$ relables elements of $D_n$. So, when $d$ runs through the divisors of $n$, $\displaystyle \frac{n}{d}$ does the same.

But notice that $\displaystyle d' \mid \frac{n}{d}$ if and only if $dd' \mid n$, therefore $dd' \in D_n$.

Now check that the function $g_{d}: D_n \to D_n$ given by $g_{d}(d') = dd'$ is bijective for any $d \in D_n$.

Since the composition of bijections is a third, the function $fog_{d}: D_n \to D_n$ is a bijection, this proves the result you want I guess. I hope that it's clear now.

Comment: Thank you ! Also why is the equality true ?

Answer (score 1):

The following equation is true for every divisor $d$ of $n$.
$$
\mu(d) F(n/d) =  \sum_{d' | (n/d)} \mu(d) f(d^{'}),
$$
so by adding these equations for all divisors you can get
$$
\sum_{d | n} \mu(d) F(n/d) =  \sum_{d | n} \sum_{d^{'} | (n/d)} \mu(d) f(d^{'}).
$$ 
But I think your question is about something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I much prefer to write that as:
\begin{align}
\mu(a) F(b)
  &= \mu(a) \sum_{c d = b} f(d) \\
\sum_{a b = n} \mu(a) F(b)
  &= \sum_{a b = n} \mu(a) \sum_{c d = b} f(d) \\
  &= \sum_{a c d = n} \mu(a) f(d) \\
  &= \sum_{e d = n} f(d) \sum_{a c = e} \mu(a) \\
  &= \sum_{e d = n} f(d) [1 = e] \\
  &= f(n)
\end{align}
Here $[\text{(condition)}]$ is Iverson's bracket, 1 is the condition is true, 0 if it is false.

This way it is clearer what factors how.